# Need to generate an JSON Array for HTML Elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

Use case 1:

```
<sub><b><i>boldSubscriptContent</i></b></sub>
```

Output JSON:

```
[{
    "subscript": true,
    "content": "boldSubscriptContent",      
    "bold": true
}]
```

Use case 2:

```
withoutAnyHTML<b>boldContent<sub>boldSubscriptContent</sub></b>
```

Output JSON :

```
[{
    "content": "WithoutAnyHTML"
}, {
    "bold": true,
    "content": "boldContent"    
}, {
    "bold": true,
    "subscript": true,
    "content": "boldSubscriptContent",
    "outerHTML": "<sub>subscriptContent</sub>"
}]
```

Use case 3:

```
<b><i>ItalicContent</i><sub>subscriptContent</sub><sup>supscriptContent</sup></b>
```

Output JSON:

```
[{
    "italic": true,
    "bold": true,
    "content": "ItalicContent",
    "outerHTML": "<i>ItalicContent</i>"
}, {
    "subscript": true,
    "bold": true,
    "content": "subscriptContent",
    "outerHTML": "<sub>subscriptContent</sub>"
}, {
    "superscript": true,
    "bold": true,
    "content": "supscriptContent",
    "outerHTML": "<sup>supscriptContent</sup>"
}]
```

Comment: Feel free to post your solution once you've finished it...

Comment: Firstly, make an attempt yourself. SO is not a code writing service. Secondly, please make your question human-readable. This was a complete mess before I edited it.

Comment: Thanks for making it correct.. using Stack overflow for the first time to post my question. Will take care from next time.

Comment: do you need to script for JSON to HTML or HTML to JSON?

Comment: Javascript code to read the data and generate the JSON data as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

[JSFiddle working link](https://jsfiddle.net/dw9ys12u/3/)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script> 
    <script>

        var res = [];

        function parseText(cont, det) {

          det = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(det));
          if (cont.tagName === 'B')
            det.b = true;
          if (cont.tagName === 'I')
            det.i = true;
          if (cont.tagName === 'U')
            det.u = true;
          if (cont.tagName === 'SUB')
            det.sub = true;
          if (cont.tagName === 'SUP')
            det.sup = true;
          if (cont.tagName) {
            for (var i = 0; i < cont.childNodes.length; i++) {
              var child = cont.childNodes[i];
              if (child.tagName) {
                parseText(child, det);
              } else {
                res.push({
                  det,
                  content: child.data
                });
              }
            }
          } else {
            res.push({
              det,
              content: cont.data
            });
          }

        }

        function calculate(){
            var str = document.getElementById('str').value;
            var cont = $('<div></div>').html(str);
            for (var i = 0; i < cont.length; i++) {
              parseText(cont[i], {
                i: false,
                b: false,
                u: false,
                sub: false,
                sup: false
              });
            }
            var resHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
              resHTML += res[i].content + "\t:" + JSON.stringify(res[i].det) + "</br>";
            }
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = resHTML;
          }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="str" value="<b>content<sup>superTest</sup><sub>subTest</sub><i>testItalic</i></b>" />
        <button onclick="calculate()">Parse</button>
        <div id = "output"></label>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I created the clone of det object in the recursive function parseText. I did this as the value of det object was reflecting same on all levels of recursive stack. 
I need experts opinion about how to use recursion in Javascript, is this the right approach, by cloning a new copy on every level of recursion.